# AST with selectors

Tags: search, language-agnostic, metaprogramming, abstract-syntax-tree

I am looking for languages / libraries which allows searching over AST for given language using selectors (ie. "/function(int, int)" to find all functions with given signature or "namespace(name=xxx)/method(name=yyy*)" to find all methods starting with yyy in given namespace).

I know there is always possibility to convert AST to XML and use XPath / XQuery, but i'am looking for something built in or easily integrable with a language.

Comment: I'd be surprised if you found such a beast; it would have to have compiler-like front ends for the variety of languages you wish to search or it wouldn't know what was a signature, let alone what the parameter types are. (you said "language-agnostic").

Comment: ... what's the emphasis on ASTs here? Where do you expect them to come from?

Comment: i wasn't hoping for one ultimate solution for all languages (I think that thing like that is being an internal project of google right now), so yes, i am interested in partial, limited and approximate solutions

Comment: AST can be given as product of external parser or generated by the very same library, it doesn't matters. I am looking for capabilities of uniformed searching into AST

Comment: You're assuming that all ASTs share some common format. I would think the AST generated from a PL's source code would vary based on the tool used to generate that AST and I'd imagine any tool used to generate an AST for a language would probably also contain a tool to manipulate/inspect the AST generated by it (or not). Do you have any specific AST generating tools in mind?

Comment: I've used a few - python builtin ast, eclipse ast parser for java, clang ast. I know they are different. Generally,  every AST library has some processing and tranforming capabilities (visitor pattern etc). So searching can be done by writing visitor's implementations. I am looking for an higher-level query interface, something like xpath for xml.

Comment: XML assumes a uniform structure for trees.

Comment: I suppose that at the structural level (namespaces, classes/traits, methods/functions/procedures, arguments and their types) it is quite possible to have an uniform structure for most of the PL? It means that there will be need of conversion from native AST to some common representation.

Comment: i know one person who used datalog for this kind of thing.  these days it might make most sense to use a graph database and query it with gremlin https://github.com/tinkerpop/gremlin/wiki.  but these are very general tools for queries on trees (or graphs) and unconnected with asts/parsing.

Comment: The above discussion assumes the hard part of the problem is solved, e.g., that somebody has all the necessary facts and they have magically been pounded into a uniform shape.  (Once there, yes, datalog is a great choice.)   Nice to assume, damn hard to find.

Comment: @Mat may I ask what is "not constructive" here?

Comment: As the question is closed, I have to add my answer as a comment: See CppDepend at http://www.cppdepend.com/ for C++ code. Gives you SQL-like query facilities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is practical :https://live.gnome.org/GObjectIntrospection/

as well as the gcc plugin dehydra : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Dehydra
LLVM has a bunch of projects : http://llvm.org/ProjectsWithLLVM/

This is theoretical: http://www.complang.org/colm/ but could be interesting.

See also this thread, on the topic of using the OWL/Semantic web for querying:
http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/semantic-web/2012Aug/0077.html

Comment: COLM is very clever parsing, focused on parsing hard langauges.  But I don't believe it offers any mature parsers, let alone symbol tables, etc.

Answer (score 1):

http://cs.nyu.edu/~lharris/content/programquerylangs.html

My focus when I was playing with things like this originally was specifically Java-oriented, also using the Eclipse AST tools. This isn't language-agnostic, and most of the tools I'm aware of aren't either.

It does, however, include some links to projects (I've only played with two of them, and not for quite some time) that may give you ideas, although it's not clear to me what kind of information you want from an answer. ASTs themselves are tied tightly to implementations.